# How do I update an Oracle DB table through SSIS

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ssis, sql-update

I am trying to update two columns from a table based off of data I have in a view. I have tried a lot of things and have had no luck. Tried using OLE DB COMMAND with no luck (always got a "not all variables bound" error. I was thinking this would be easy. Does anyone have any expereince with this that could help?

Comment: How would I be able to reproduce this error? is the view on the Oracle side? If not then it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Script Task to run UPDATE and everything works now.